# Prolog program to convert(L,X) that converts list L to an integer: x1 + x2*10^1+ … + xn*10^(n-1)

Tags: recursion, lambda, prolog, swi-prolog

My Problem: Given a list

```
L = [x1,...,xn]
```

write a Prolog program `convert(L,X)` that converts `L` to an integer

```
x1*10^0 + x2*10^1 + ... + xn*10^(n-1)
```

storing the the result in `X`.

For example

```
?- convert( [1,2,3,4] , Res ).
Res = 4321.
```

I was trying to solve this problem, but I'm getting syntax error where i'm trying to use built-in function of power. This is what I have so far:

```
convert([],Res) .
convert(L1,Res) :- conv( L1 , Res , C ) .

conv( [] , Res , C ) .
conv( [H|Ys] , Res , C ):-
  C1 is C-1 ,
  N is (H*(10**C)) ,
  conv(Ys,Res2,C1) ,
  Res is N + Res2 .
```

I get this error:

```
******* syntax error
>>>   conv ( [ H | Ys ] , Res , C ) :- C1 is C - 1 , N is ( H * ( 10  <--- HERE? >>>
```

So somebody can tell me how to get rid of this error??

Plus is there any way I'm going wrong syntactically??

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you use SWI-Prolog, this works :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

convert(L,Res) :-
    reverse(L, LR),
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(Z is Y * 10 + X), LR, 0, Res).
```

For your code :

```
convert([],Res) . <== Here Res is a free variable
convert(L1,Res) :-conv(L1,Res,C). <== here C is free

conv([],Res,C). <== Here Res anc C are free
```

This can't work; You can try

```
conv([],0).
conv([H|Ys],Res):-
  conv(Ys,Res2),
  Res is Res2 * 10 + H.
```

Comment: I just downloaded the current stable release but I says it can't find the lambda library

Comment: Module lambda can be loaded at http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl

Comment: I was just confused as you mention SWI Prolog specifically. Does the lambda.pl use any non-ISO syntax?

Comment: yes, see this page http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord

Answer (score 0):

The original poster was on the right track. This will do, though, without using `library(lambda)`:

```
convert( Xs , R ) :-        % to sum a list of values, scaling each by their corresponding power of 10,
  convert( Xs , 1 , 0 , R ) % just invoke the worker predicate, seeding the power accumulator with 10^0 (1)
  .                         % and the result accumulator with zero (0).

convert( []     , _ , R , R ) .   % when we exhaust the source list, we're done: unify the result R with the result accumulator
convert( [X|Xs] , P , T , R ) :-  % otherwise...
  T1 is T + X*P ,                 % - increment the result accumulator by the current list item, scaled by the current power of 10,
  P1 is P*10 ,                    % - bump up to the next power of 10, and
  convert(Xs,P1,T1,R)             % - recurse down.
  .                               %
```

It can also be done using Prolog's built-in exponentiation (but it's neither simpler, nor faster):

```
convert( Xs , R ) :-
  convert(Xs,0,0,R)
  .

convert( []     , _ , R , R ) .
convert( [X|Xs] , N , T , R ) :-
  T1 is T + X * 10**N ,
  N1 is N+1 ,
  convert1(Xs,N1,T1,R)
  .
```

The easiest and most elegant way, though (at least in SWI, Quintus or Sicstus) would be to use `library(aggregate)` and write the one-liner:

```
convert( Xs , R ) :- aggregate( sum(X*10**N) , nth0(N,Xs,X) , R ) .
```